# Clustered primary key on unique identifier ID column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

If your ID column on a table is a unique identifier (Guid), is there any point creating a **clustered** primary key on the ID column?

Given that they are globally unique, how would the sorting work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GUIDs as they are are terrible for performance since they are effectively random values (this "breaks" clustered index), and they are awful for indexes, since less entries fit on a single page/extent (SQL Server terms). SQL Server 2005 introduces [`newsequentialid()`](http://www.sqljunkies.com/Article/4067A1B1-C31C-4EAF-86C3-80513451FC03.scuk) which helps solving first problem.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly advise against using clustered Guid key... We had big performance issues on SQL server because of such poor design a few years ago.

Also check out: [Improving performance of cluster index GUID primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583001/improving-performance-of-cluster-index-guid-primary-key)

Answer (score 3):

Putting a clustered index on a guid column is not such a good idea (unless you're making use of sequential guids).

The clustered index determines the physical order of how the records are stored.
This means that, if you put a clustered index on a column that does not sequentially grow,  SQL Server will have some work making sure that the records are correctly ordered physically when you insert new records.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of having a sorted index is very good in itself as searching then becomes very efficient.

The problem however is that in case of a GUID one never searches with "WHERE GUID = xyz". So the whole concept is wasted. So I would suggest to rather have a clustered index on a column which is used most often as a SARG to increase the query efficiency.

Comment: I think "WHERE GUID = xyz" is used a lot, in selecting single records. But ab "ORDER BY guid" would be very rare.