# benefits of using unique identifiers as primary key? in sql server

Tags: sql-server

as opposed to int or bigint?

Also what are some drawbacks? slower performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate (one of many) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713430/clustered-primary-key-on-unique-identifier-id-column-in-sql-server

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys

Answer (score 2):

The only benefit I can think of is that it may make the table more "human" readable.  Potential drawbacks and things to consider are:

- Is it truly a unique identifier?
- Performance may be affected depending on how large you need to scale.  You may need to check if SQL Server indexes' performance is impacted.

Personally, I prefer a surrogate key number that uses an auto-increment, but it really depends on your situation.

If you were referring to the SQL Server IDENTITY column, then you may want to check out the following article, which I found helpful.
[Understanding SQL Server Identity Columns](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-identity-columns)