# SQL Server turn off ANSI_WARNING ON A stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to know how to turn off ANSI warnings on my stored procedure please. I keep getting the error

> *String or binary data would be truncated.*

However, I would rather this be turned off so as I expect this and would rather allow it.

I added the statement

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
```

right before the stored procedure however, doing this does not seem to suppress the error at all.

For the reason why I have this truncate error to begin with, well one of my stored procs executes dynamic Sql to retrieve values([SQLFIddle showing the code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10876/1) ). And I had to set the length on all of my fields to the length of the max (NVarchar(3072)). When my query is executed however, I need them back to the right size when printing them to the client.

Would appreciate info on how to best deal with this please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should fix the actual **problem** - that you're trying to insert something that's too long for the column it's being inserted into - rather than just turn the warning off...

Comment: The problem is not really a problem per say. I used a dynamic query in one of my stored procs that required I declare all values to be of the same size (3072). So in the calling procedure, I try to reset the size of the fields back to what they should be.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @marc_s -- fix the problem, not the symptom **especially if your intent is to truncate**.  What will another developer think when he comes along and a proc is throwing these errors and a non standard flag was used to suppress the issue?

> *Code to make your intent to truncate clear.*

**Identifying your Problem**
The fiddle doesn't display the behavior your describe.  So I'm still a little confused as to the issue.

Also, your SQL fiddle is *way too dense* for a question like this. If I don't answer your question below work to isolate the problem to the simplest use case possible.  Don't just dump 500 lines of your app into a window.

*Note:  The Max NVarchar is either 4000 in version of SQL 7 & 2000 or 2 Gigs (`nvarchar(max)`) in SQL 2005 and later.   I have no idea where you came up with 3072.*

**My Test**

If you're truncating at the SPROC *parameter* level, ANSI Warnings flags is ignored, as [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx) warns.   If it's inside your procedure, I created a little test proc that displays the ANSI flag allowing truncation:

```
CREATE Proc DoSomething (@longThing varchar(50)) AS 

   DECLARE @T1 TABLE  ( shortThing VARCHAR(20) );

   SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
   Print ' I don''t even whimpler when truncating'
   INSERT INTO @T1 (ShortThing) VALUES ( @longThing);

   SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
   Print ' I yell when truncated'
   INSERT INTO @T1 (ShortThing) VALUES ( @longThing);
```

Then calling it the following works as expected:

```
exec DoSomething 'Text string longer than 20 characters'
```

**FIXING THE PROBLEM**

Nevertheless, why not just code so your intent to (potentially) truncate data is clear? You can avoid the warning rather than turn it off.  I would do one of the following:

- make your Procedure parameters long enough to accommodate the input
- IF you need to shorten string data use `Substring()` to trim data.
- Use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to format the data to your requirement.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (section headed "Implicit Conversions" should help) details how cast & convert work.

My simple example above can be modified as follows to avoid the need to set any flag.

```
CREATE Proc DoSomethingBETTER (@longThing varchar(50)) AS 

   SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON  
   DECLARE @T1 TABLE  ( shortThing VARCHAR(20) );


   --try one of these 3 options...
   INSERT INTO @T1 (ShortThing) VALUES ( Convert(varchar(20), @longThing));
   INSERT INTO @T1 (ShortThing) VALUES ( Substring(@longThing, 1, 20));
   INSERT INTO @T1 (ShortThing) VALUES ( Cast(@longThing as varchar(20)) );

   Print('Ansi warnings can be on when truncating data');
```

#### An Aside - Clustered Guids

Looking at your fiddle I noticed that you `Uniqueidentifer` as the key in your Clustered indexes.   In almost every scenario this is a pretty inefficient option.  The randomness of GUIDs means your data is constantly being fragmented & re-shuffled.

Hopefully you can convert to `int identity`, you're using `newsequentialid()`, or COMB guids as described in  [Jimmy Nilsson's article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862).
You can see more about the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713430/clustered-primary-key-on-unique-identifier-id-column-in-sql-server), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583001/improving-performance-of-cluster-index-guid-primary-key), [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727090/unique-identifier-guid-as-primary-key-in-database-design).