# Entity Framework Algorithm For Combining Data

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This pertains to a project I am inheriting and cannot change table structure or data access model.  I have been asked to optimize the algorithm being used to insert data into the database.

We have a dataset in table T.  From that, we pull a set we will call A.  We also query an XML feed and get a set we will call X.

- If a value from X is in A, record in A must be updated to reflect data for X.record
- If a value from X is not in A, X.record must be inserted into A
- If a value from A is not in X, A.record must be preserved in A
- X must be fully iterated through for all records, and A must be updated

All these changes need to be insert back into the database.

The algo as set up does the following:

```
Query XML into a LIST
foreach over the XML LIST
    look up foreach.item in A via LINQ (i.e. query = from record in A where
                                                         record.GUID == foreach.item.GUID
                                                         select record)
    if query.Count() == 0
        insert into A (via context.AddToTableName(newTableNameObject)
    else
        var currentRecord = query.First()
        set all properties on currentRecord = properties from foreach.item
        context.SaveChanges()
```

I know this to be suboptimal.  I tried to get A into a object (call it queryA) outside of the foreach loop in an effort to move the query to memory and not hitting the disk, but after thinking that through, I realized the database was already in memory.

Having added timer objects into the algo, it's clear that what is costing the most time is the SaveChanges() function call.  In some cases it's 20ms, and in some others, in explicably, it will jump to 100ms.

I would prefer to only call the SaveChanges() one time.  I can't figure out how to do that given my depth of knowledge of EF (which is thin at best) and the constraints of not being able to change the table structures and having to preserve data from A which is not in X.

Suggestions?

Comment: You mention that you cannot change the data access model.  So it's not possible to bulk insert the flattened XML and run a `MERGE` within the target database?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that you will improve the performance when using Entity framework:

**The query**

- Loading each record by separate query is not good
- You can improve the performance by loading multiple records in the same query. For example you can load small batch of records by using either || in condition or `Contains` (like `IN` in SQL). `Contains` is supported only by .NET 4.0.
- Another improvement can be replacing the query with stored procedure and [table valued parameter](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) to pass all guids to SQL server join A with X.Guids and get results. Table valued parameters are only supported on SQL 2008 and newer.

**The data modification**

- You <strike>don't have to</strike> should not call `SaveChanges` after each modification. You can call it after foreach loop and it will still work. It will pass all modifications in single transaction <strike>but you will not get any performance boost by such operation</strike> and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework/5942176#5942176) it can give you a significant boost.
- [EF doesn't support command batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407348/batching-db-commands-in-entity-framework-4-0) and because of that each update or insert always takes separate round trip to the database. There is no way around this when using EF to modify data except implementing whole new EF ADO.NET provider (it is like starting a new project).
- Again solution is reducing roundtrips by using stored procedure with table valued parameter
- If your DB also uses that GUID as primary key and clustered index you have another performance decrease by [reordering index after each insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583001/improving-performance-of-cluster-index-guid-primary-key) = modifying data on disk.

The problem is not in algorithm but in the way you process the data and technology used to process the data. Entity framework is not a good choice for data pumps. You should go with these information to your boss because improving performance means more complicated change in your application. It is not your fault and it is not the fault of the programmer who did the application. This is a feature of EF which is not very well known and as I know it is not clearly stated in any MS best practices.

Comment: "but you will not get any performance boost by such operation.": I had an extreme performance boost for mass inserts when I don't call `SaveChanges()` after each record. Did you see my measurement here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework/5942176#5942176 Perhaps I did something wrong or for updates it is another story than for inserts.

Comment: @Slauma: I trust your experiment and perhaps I will try it later myself. I modified my answer.

Comment: look at my comments on this answare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework/5942176#5942176 SavinChanges after each insert FOR ME was doing the overhead, implementing the solution provided by sluma reduced Dramatically the time of insertion