# Entity Framework mergeoption notracking bad performance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a strange behavior trying to execute a query declaring ObjectQuery MergeOption to "NoTracking", in this case entity framework should not attach any entity and not create the relative ObjectStateEntry to track entity state.

The problem is that instead of increase performance it get worse, the same query takes like 10 seconds with default mergeoption (that is AppendingOnly) and more the 1 minutes if I try to specify notracking

Does someone have an explanation for this??

Comment: How did you measure query executions?

Comment: basically taking a timestamp before and after the query executed with a ToList()

Comment: But how many times do you execute query and what order of executions are you using?

Comment: I execute the query one time but I have tried to make multiple executions and it obviously gets faster but the "notracking" query is still slower than the "appendingonly". What does "oderd of executions" means?

Comment: Just compare single execution of both. If you execute both in single application run also try to execute them in reverse order.

Comment: I don't understand, I don't execute them in order, it is the same query that I try to execute with or without notracking option

Answer (score 190, accepted):

If you disable change tracking by setting the `NoTracking` merge option you save the performance costs of attaching objects to the contexts but on the other hand you also lose identity management.

This means that potentially much more objects - many with the same key - will be materialized.

Example: Suppose you have a `User` entity with a `Roles` collection as navigation property. Also suppose you have 1 million users in the database and all users are in the same 10 roles, i.e. every user has a roles collection with 10 elements. If you run the following query...

```
var users = context.Users.Include("Roles").ToList();
```

...the number of materialized and instantiated objects depends on the merge option:

- If you don't use `NoTracking` you will have 1.000.010 objects in memory, namely 1 million users, but only 10 roles because identity mapping will ensure that only 1 role per key is materialized and attached to the context. The same 10 role instances are used for all user's `Roles` collection.
- If you use `NoTracking` however, EF won't attach objects to the context, hence identity management is disabled and you will have 11.000.000 objects in memory: 1 million users and 10 role instances per user, i.e. 10 million role objects. So, you have more than 10 times as many materialized objects as when the objects are attached to the context.

Object materialization is classified with ["moderate" performance costs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx):

> **Operation: Materializing the objects**
>
> **Relative Cost: Moderate**
>
> **Frequency: Once for each object that a query returns.**
>
>
> **Comments:**
> The process of reading the returned DbDataReader object and creating
> objects and setting property values that are based on the values in
> each instance of the DbDataRecord class. **If the object already exists
> in the ObjectContext and the query uses the *AppendOnly* or
> *PreserveChanges* merge options, this stage does not affect performance.**

In other words: If the query uses the `NoTracking` merge option, this stage **does affect performance** and it might be possible that the performance benefits of disabled change tracking are destroyed by the drawbacks of disabled identity management and multiplied object materialization.

Since EF Core 5.0 there is the additional option ['NoTrackingWithIdentityResolution'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#identity-resolution) which disables general tracking but will do identity resolution.

Comment: Does this still apply? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking says: No tracking queries still perform identity resolution within the executing query. If the result set contains the same entity multiple times, the same instance of the entity class will be returned for each occurrence in the result set. However, weak references are used to keep track of entities that have already been returned. If a previous result with the same identity goes out of scope, and garbage collection runs, you may get a new entity instance. For more information, see How Query Works.

Comment: It just became relevant again with EF Core 3.0
Your linked documentation states this change:
"No-tracking queries [...] don't do identity resolution. So you get back new instance of entity even when the same entity is contained in the result multiple times. This behavior was different in versions before EF Core 3.0"