# How Entity Framework generates queries?

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

For last 5-6 months, I've started using EF Code First for all my data access needs in .net projects.
However, most of the time I got complaints from clients about that the webpages are slow.

I've recently took some time and drilled down this issue and it seems most of the time is being consumed by EF. 
Normally the database has about few ten thousands of records, and only couple of tables. I regularly use standard LINQ queries to manipulate database. Also, I use repository and unit of work patterns in my EF codes. I apply indexes to database.

All I do is nothing magic, just regular/standard suggested ways.

Is EF taking so long to generate queries, or there is something I might be missing? Why data access is so slow even if I use standard algorithms and suggested ways?

Comment: I suggest you learn what caching is.

Comment: Have you looked into compiled queries?

Comment: I always used EF 5, for my last project I used EF 6. I thought that EF 5+ will cache the query automatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347670/entity-framework-is-too-slow-what-are-my-options

Comment: the above post in SO, shows that EF is slow somehow when queries are complex.:( my goodness, i think i need to switch back to my old style data access with stored procedure.