# Is anonymous type better choice to DTO/POCO?

Tags: c#, json, performance, dto, anonymous-types

Returning json data through a web request lead us to make it lighter and faster. So I was wondering, what is better to return: a anonymous object or a DTO?

I've read some concerns about architecture: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1018716/Replacing-DTO-with-Anonymous-object
and use of DTOs: [Entity Framework is Too Slow. What are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347670/entity-framework-is-too-slow-what-are-my-options)
But it's not my focus, I want to know what is lighter and faster on returning a web request.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't put a lot of weight in that CodeProject article.  It's written by one guy and has no feedback.  He doesn't really go into the downside, only shows how it _can_ be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no significant difference as far as "weight" or performance.  Anonymous objects *are* classes just like DTOs, they just aren't defined at design-time, they are defined by the compiler.

The *disadvangates* of using anonymous types is that they are not type-safe outside of the method that defines it.  It "works" when returning JSON because it uses reflection to get all of the properties of the type, just like a "normal" class.

The benefit of anonymous type is purely coding efficiency - you don't have to define a "type" for use within a single method.  If, however, that type is going to be exposed by the method (whether directly or through JSON) then you should define a type for it.