# Is it okay to have non sequential ids as primary keys for a table in your database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, primary-key

I don't know enough about databases to find the right words to ask this question, so let me give an example to explain what I'm trying to do: Suppose I want the primary key for a table to be an ID I grab from an API, but the majority of those API requests result in 404 errors. As a result, my table would look like this:

I also don't know how to format a table-like structure on Stack Overflow, so this is going to be a rough visual:

```
API_ID_PK | name
------------------
1         | Billy
5         | Timmy
23        | Richard
54        | Jobert
104       | Broccoli
```

Is it okay for the ID's not to be sequentially separated by 1 digit? Or should I do this:

```
ID PK |  API_ID   | NAME
----------------------------------------
1     |    1      | Billy
2     |    5      | Timmy
3     |    23     | Richard
4     |    54     | Jobert
5     |    104    | Broccoli
```

Would the second table be more efficient for indexing reasons? Or is the first table perfectly fine? Thanks!

Comment: ya i'm pretty sure ID's are automatically incremented by one

Comment: @Coffee: IDs are automatically incremented by one **only by default**. This can be changed, however. See my answer.

Comment: @tobogganjester: Shouldn't matter. For all the DB knows is you had all consecutive, but deleted 2...4, 6...22, 24...53, etc. (though if there are PKs from another database, you could put your mind at ease and make your own PK, then specify these as a `tmdb_id` column.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there won't be any effect on efficiency if you have non-consecutive IDs. In fact, MySQL (and other databases) allow for you to set a variable [`auto_increment_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) to have the ID increment by more than 1. This is commonly used in multi-master setups.

Comment: What if it's an arbitrary sequence? OP's IDs above don't have any pattern at all, just random

Comment: Doesn't matter, the only requirement for IDs is that they be unique.

Comment: @Coffee: The ID is usually used to create a binary-tree of some sort. Thus, as TMN states, the only requirement is that they be unique.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to have IDs not sequential. I regularly use GUIDs for IDs when dealing with enterprise software where multiple business could share the same object and they're never sequential.

The one thing to watch out for is if the numbers are the same. What's determining the ID value you're storing?

Comment: I'm dumping movie data from Themoviedb, so each tmdb id is unique, just a lot of them end up being deleted by tmdb, and their policy is to keep that ID unused. I was just worried about efficiency if it's not 1 2 3 4 5 etc.

Comment: It sounds like you're fine. ID mapping like what you're experiencing is common. You'll want to handle cases their API throws at you, such as if they return lists sorted by last-modified date (which could return the same record to you in successive calls). MySQL handles this with "on duplicate key update". Good Luck!

Comment: Using non sequential uuid as primary key will effect the insertion performance? Reason is primary keys are clustered index.

Comment: SQL Server stores indexes in a B-Tree structure. Other than the large size (16 bytes) of the GUID data type, I expect for it to perform equally. Studies indicate that B-Trees perform better with randomly inserted values. The question should be on appropriateness. You can create surrogate keys that are smaller in size (like the 4-Byte Integer), which would allow the scanning to go by faster just because there's less data to compare. However, doing so would negate the universal uniqueness of the ID. In a closed system, GUIDs might be overkill, but in an openly shared system, uniqueness matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a clustered index (Sql-Server) on a ID column and insert IDs with random values (like Guids), this can have a negative effect, as the physical order of the clustered index corresponds to the logical order. This can lead to a lot of index re-organisations. See: [Improving performance of cluster index GUID primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/583030/880990).

However, ordered but non consecutive values (values not separated by 1) are not a problem for clustered indexes.

For non-clustered indexes the order doesn't matter. It is okay to insert random values for primary keys as long as they are unique.